# Is localStorage a good way to go when building an workorder for mySQL query is user is offline?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm building a web app that will update MySQL when the user comes online.

I have this form where the user enters data.
The formData saves into "localStorage" is the user is offline and when the user goes online a javascript is fetching data from the localStorage and then send it through AJAX to PHP and MySQL.

Is this a way to go or are there better ways to create a list for offline users?

I'm also using a serviceWorker to cache the static html and js pages.

```
//ADD DATA TO localStorage (data contains the formData)
localStorage.setItem(id, JSON.stringify(data));

//FETCH DATA (this is in a loop)
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is..

I did this and it works good